# Coded UI Testing System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

```
public class portal
{
     public  portal()
    {
    }
     [DataSource ("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.TestCase", "http://alm:8080/tfs/....", "15729", DataAccessMethod.Sequential), TestMethod]

     public static void portalmtm()
     {
         BrowserWindow b = BrowserWindow.Launch(new System.Uri(TestContext.DataRow["portals"].ToString()));
     }

    public static TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }
    private static TestContext testContextInstance;

    }
}
```

It gives an error when I use it in codeduitest (testmethod) 
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object. What is the problem? What can I do?Thanks...

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test1()
    {          
        portalmtm();
        this.UIMap....
        this.UIMap....
    }
  public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get
        {
            return testContextInstance;
        }
        set
        {
            testContextInstance = value;
        }
    }
    private TestContext testContextInstance;
```

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net

Comment: `TestContext` is never initialized.

Comment: Where is your CodedUiTest? You have defined it as a simple TestMethod.

Comment: How to initialize testcontext?

Answer (score 1):

The class has to be decorated with the `CodedUITestAttribute` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Put [TestMethod] above the method like this and it should work. (TestMethod) means nothing, you must use the square brackets.

```
     [TestMethod]
     public static void portalmtm()
     {
         //Code goes here.
     }
```

By the way if your going to put any automated test methods in this I'm pretty sure it cannot be static.